# PWM/clock signal generation from a USB-1024HLS DAQ board

Tags: matlab, hardware

Is there an API function call for this board that would allow me to generate a clock signal on an output at 500 kHz while running some other code on the board? Thanks in advance for the advices.

Comment: Are you wanting to output both a clock signal and a PWM signal simultaneously? That should be doable, but doing it at 500 kHz seems like it might be a problem. I have the feeling that may end up being too fast for MATLAB to handle, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Any luck with the clock signal? Can MATLAB handle such a high frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Supported Hardware documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/daq/supportedio14004.html), version 2.8 or greater of the [Data Acquisition Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/daq_product_page.html) is needed to support a Measurement Computing USB-1024HLS device. Assuming you have version 2.8 or newer, the following should come close to a solution for you...

The first step would be to get the hardware ID for the device. The function [DAQHWINFO](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/daqhwinfo.html) should help with this:

```
deviceInfo = daqhwinfo('mcc');
```

The hardware ID gotten from the structure **deviceInfo** can then be used to create a Digital I/O Object (DIO) using the [DIGITALIO](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/digitalio.html) function:

```
dio = digitalio('mcc',hardwareID);
```

Next, you have to add two output lines (for a clock signal and a pulse-width modulation (PWM) signal) using [ADDLINE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/addline.html):

```
addline(dio,0:1,'out');
```

Then, you have to set a few DIO properties.

```
set(dio,'TimerPeriod',0.000002);  % i.e. 500 kHz
set(dio,'TimerFcn',@update_outputs);
```

The function **update_outputs** is called once every timer period and should set the output pins to the appropriate values. The [clock signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal) is simply going to switch back and forth between 0 and 1 every timer period. The [PWM signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) will likely alternate between 0 and 1 as well, but it will not change every timer period, remaining in each state for a set amount of time based upon the sort of pulse-width modulation you want. Here's what your **update_outputs** function may end up looking like:

```
function update_outputs(obj,event)
  currentValues = getvalue(obj);
  clockValue = ~currentValues(1);
  pwmValue = pwm_compute();
  putvalue(obj,[clockValue pwmValue]);
end
```

Note that this uses [PUTVALUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/putvalue.html) and [GETVALUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/getvalue.html) to set/get the values of the output pins. You will have to write the function **pwm_compute** such that it computes a new PWM value for each time period. Since **pwm_compute** will likely have to know how many values have been output already (i.e. how many times it has already been called), you can track that using a [persistent variable](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html):

```
function newValue = pwm_compute
  persistent nValues;
  if isempty(nValues)
    nValues = 0;
  else
    nValues = nValues+1;
  end
  ...
  % Compute the new value for the (nValues+1) time period
  ...
end
```

This is just one possible solution. You could potentially precompute the PWM signal and pull the value for each timer period from a vector or data file, or you could potentially use the [**event** data structure](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/timerfcn.html) passed to **update_outputs** to get the time of the timer event (relative to the DIO timer start, I believe).

Finally, you have to start the DIO:

```
start(dio);
```

...and, once you're finished using it, delete it and clear it from memory:

```
delete(dio);
clear dio;
```

### One potential stumbling block...

Generating a 500 kHz signal could be difficult. It's such a high frequency that you *may* run into problems, specifically with the 'TimerFcn', which is called once every timer period. If the 'TimerFcn' takes longer than 0.000002 seconds to run, [some timer events may not be processed](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/timerfcn.html), leading to an output that is actually of a lower frequency. I have a feeling you may have to use a lower signal frequency for things to work properly, but I could be wrong. =)

Comment: According to http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/daq_product_page.html, the newest version of Data Acquisition Toolbox is 2.14, but I have still managed to communicate to my DAQ somehow. I just haven't implemented the clock signal yet (that you have suggested). It would be great if I can hear your thoughts about the Data Acquisition Toolbox version from what you have read. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: If you have the newest version, you're good. It's "two-point-fourteen" as opposed to "two-point-one-four", if that was the confusion (i.e. it is 6 better than "two-point-eight"). =)

Answer (score 1):

I found [Example: Generating Timer Events](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/daq/f11-16754.html#f11-12837) in the Data Acquisition Toolbox documentation.

```
dio = digitalio('nidaq','Dev1');
addline(dio,0:7,'in');
set(dio,'TimerFcn',@daqcallback)
set(dio,'TimerPeriod',5.0)
start(dio)
pause(11)
delete(dio)
clear dio
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It may take me a day or two to get a chance to test it out on the hardware though. I'll let you know how it goes.